# Regulate how many PDF pages is to be displayed per page in when knitting to PDF in Rmarkdown?

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown document where I import a few PDFs, and I would like to display four PDF-import-pages per page in my knitted PDF.

```
---
title: "combinePages"
author: "xxx"
date: '2022-xx-xx'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}
---
\includepdf[pages={-}]{pdfs/Lecture1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={-}]{pdfs/Lecture2.pdf}
```

Can this be done in rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [manual](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) of `pdfpages`,

> `nup` => Puts multiple logical pages onto each sheet of paper. The syntax of this option is: nup=⟨xnup⟩x⟨ynup⟩. Where ⟨xnup⟩ and ⟨ynup⟩ specify the umber of logical pages in horizontal and vertical direction, which are arranged on each sheet of paper. (Default: nup=1x1)

So, four pdf pages from an imported pdf file can be knitted per page using `nup=2x2` in the option of `\includepdf`.

---

```
---
title: "combinePages"
author: "xxx"
date: '2022-xx-xx'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}
---

## Multiple Page

\includepdf[pages={1-}, nup=2x2]{lorem_ipsum.pdf}

\includepdf[pages={1-}, nup=2x2]{lorem_ipsum.pdf}
```

---

So A page of the rendered document looks like this,

[image: four_page_in_one]

---

Explore the [manual](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for more options.